# Slider not working on Mac, any idea why? Not able to reproduce

Tags: jquery, macos, slider

As the tree said to the lumberjack, I'm stumped.  Please see http://cookware.lecreuset.com

The slider isn't working on a Mac OSX when viewed outside of my wireless network. I am not able to reproduce the issue because it works fine on the Mac, iPad and iPhone I have access to in-house. Browserlab doesn't show the functionality in any browser, so that won't help.

If any one has any ideas why this isn't working on a Mac, please share. Also, any tips on troubleshooting issues like this if I can't reproduce on the machines I have available? Maybe there's something I can download that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your js files seems to load. Geting `404` for the following files

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://lecreuset-stg2.crossview.inc/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/hp-slider/jquery.cycle.js"
jquery.cycle.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://lecreuset-stg2.crossview.inc/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/hp-slider/slideshow.js"
slideshow.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://lecreuset-stg2.crossview.inc/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/hp-slider/jquery.cycle.js"
jquery.cycle.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://lecreuset-stg2.crossview.inc/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/hp-slider/slideshow.js"
```

Also when I tried opening any of the above in a browser window I got

`Your requested host "lecreuset-stg2.crossview.inc" could not be resolved by DNS.`

Comment: Wow, I feel like such a dummy. Forgot to point the links away from the staging site, which is being worked on right now.  But why would it work on everything but a Mac?

Comment: Because you are using them on your personal network that might have a mapping to the staging server